# How does google analytics deal with source UTM and referral conflicts?

Tags: google-analytics, utm-parameters

How does google analytics deal with source UTM and referral conflicts?

For instance if i have a link like this `http://example.com/?utm_source=test` hosted on a 3rd party site, if someone visits that link, would the visit show up in Google Analytics as `source = other / test` or `source = referral 3rdparty.com`?

Or would Google analytics deal with this in some other way?

Answer (score 1):

UTM information in the URL overrides referral in Google Analytics (Universal Analytics). At least if you fill the 3 required fields: utm_campaign, utm_source and utm_medium.